# Creating clean and standard API with different type of clients

Tags: javascript, php, python, node.js, api

I want to create an api that various clients can connect to it like Web, Mobile platforms etc. My problem is that sometimes things are different with each client. For example i use different method for authentication for Web and Mobile platforms and my question is:

> I have to create different files for each type of client or use if
>   else statements to detect client type and do proper functions in the
>   same class?

I want to create clean and standard API. I know this can have a lots of answers and its a broad question, But i just have a clue in this.

Comment: I've never heard of an API where it differs from Desktop and Mobile login. The user just sends authentication data, never-mind what their platform is, and the server gives them a cookie if they have valid credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NO stick to a standard
```

If you are doing an API based you will first have to standardize the calls, you cant have X,Y,Z for a single function for different client. This will one day go out of hand.

You must come into a standard agreement about the functions to be used, I am sure that at the client side this will require a minimum change as I presume the return types will be same.

Furthermore it will be difficult to maintain by a new developer.

So stick to standard call and get into a common agreement.

Answer (score 2):

Well one of the most and the easiest way i've found to make Web-Service using [YII 2.0 Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)

What you need to do.

1. Create your database schema
2. Make Active Models using [Gii tool](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tool-gii.html) for each table
3. Make [Rest Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html#creating-a-controller) for each your model
4. Use [Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server](https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server) library for Authentication
5. Use Yii 2.0 [RBAC](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md) if required

You can create API modules like api/v1 for desktop clients and api/v2 for mobile clients for that you can easily separate [Access Controls](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html). Checkout the [example](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-versioning.md) for separating API versions Or if you don't want do every thing manually just clone [karas/yii2-oauth2-rest-template](https://github.com/ikaras/yii2-oauth2-rest-template) which has all the major functionalities included.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely not 'the one and only' way to create an API.

However, checking the type of client is definitely not the way to go, as it would mean checking headers, which can be forged when sending the request.

For authentication, if you want to use different methods, your best bet is probably to have different authentication strategies, and try them one after the other. If the first fail, you run the next, etc.
A common way to implement this is to add an authentication middleware, which tries each available strategy to authenticate the client, and stops the request if it could not.

This does mean that even if you want your strategy A to work only for the browser, it could also be used to login from a mobile app, but there is no way to prevent this, and anyway it should not lead to any security issue either. If it does, the issue is probably somewhere else.